# How to highlight fields when a validation error is fired?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

I have an apex validation that fires when a field is empty.My requirement is **highlight** two fields that needs to filled, when the validation is fired.

How to do that ?Could someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the addError method on the field:

```
if(aRecord.Some_Field__c == null) {
  aRecord.Some_Field__c.addError('This field is required when...');
}
```

In the UI, the errored field will have a red border with the provided message, and an icon will appear at the bottom of the page to indicate an error, with a link that will scroll the errored field into view.